# Filter "bad path" results in mdfind

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, scripting

Okay, so I have a script that is running a command to get a list of file-names, however some of them might not actually exist. What I'd like to do is filter this list through a pipe and remove any file-name that doesn't actually exist.

In case it helps any the command I'm using is OS X's mdfind (Spotlight search) which, given some search criteria, will rapidly return a list of matching file-names (actually, absolute paths); the problem is that it's possible for Spotlight to return some garbage results, usually "bad path " so I need to filter these out so I can pass the list into another program.

Comment: Why would some of the files not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try piping your `mdfind` command through `grep`:

```
mdfind __your-query-args__ | grep -iv "bad path"
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks Rodney and @glenn, both methods work, but this one seems the cleaner of the two as items returned by mdfind should actually exist (sorry if I confused my question), and I'll probably be piping through gzip and into a file so this should be easiest to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your shell is bash:

```
result=()
mdfind ... | while IFS= read -r filename; do
  [[ -e $filename ]] && result+=("$filename")
done
```

The `IFS=` and `-r` bits are there to properly handle files with whitespace or escaped characters.

The array `result` contains the existing files. Use it as a list with `"${result[@]}"` (with the quotes) or iterate over it with

```
for file in "${result[@]}"; do something "$file"; done
```